# Ребят поможете сделать export JSON, HTML,CSV,PDF?

Tags: phpstorm, twig, symfony3

Этот код выводит только формат json, а как вывести другие форматы?

```
/**
 * Export action.
 *
 * @return RedirectResponse
 *
 * @Route("/export", name="export")
 * @Template()
 */
public function exportAction()
{
    $exporter = $this->get('fungio.dataexporter');
    $Lead = new Lead();

    $exporter->setOptions('json', array('fileName' => 'file', 'separator' => ';'));
    $exporter->setColumns(array('firstName' => 'firstName', 'mobilePhone' => 'mobilePhone', 'country' => 'country'));
    $exporter->setData(array($Lead));


    return $exporter->render();
}
```

Вот twig:

```
{% extends '::dashboard.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <h2>{{ 'contact.export'|trans }}</h2>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li>
            <a href="/">{{ 'home'|trans }}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <strong>{{ 'contact.export'|trans }}</strong>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<a href="{{ path("export") }}">JSON</a>
<a href="{{ path("") }}">XML</a>
<a href="{{ path("") }}">HTML </a>
<a href="{{ path("") }}">CSV</a>
<a href="{{ path("") }}">XLS</a>
<a href="{{ path("") }}">PDF</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Хоть подскажи как я дальше сам пойму

Comment: С начало было бы не плохо посмотреть класс fungio.dataexporter. Как я вижу из это строки  $exporter->setOptions('json', array('fileName' => 'file', 'separator' => ';'));. В ней передаётся формат.

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример вывода в CSV `$exporter->setOptions('csv', array('fileName' => 'file', 'separator' => ';', 'memory', 'skip_header'));`

Документация по бандлу [тут](https://github.com/fungio/FungioDataExporterBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md).